# Is it possible to have the GUI available while downloading a file in R?

Tags: r, httr

Suppose one is downloading a pretty big file through `httr`. The download proceeds, but is somewhat slow. Is there any way of rendering the R GUI available while the download is in progress?

This is a working example. The file being downloaded is an example file.

> ```
> library(httr)
> ex <- "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip"
>
> httr::GET(ex, progress(), verbose(), write_disk(paste(getwd(), "example", sep = "/")))
> ```

Comment: Do you not already have the GUI open when running this script? Are you using `Rscript` or something? I'm not sure exactly what you are referring to.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, the GUI is open, but the file is being downloaded. The console is unusable while the file is being downloaded.

Comment: Which GUI are you talking about, on which OS?

Comment: @user2554330 I am using the basic R distribution, and I am running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Windows much, but I just tried clicking on the Rgui shortcut while another copy was running your download code, and it opened a new copy of the GUI that appeared to work.

You'd want to be a bit careful doing this:  changing the installed packages would likely cause trouble, and if you save your workspace at the end of a session (which is a **bad** idea), the second one you save will likely wipe out the first one.

But the answer appears to be "yes, just open another copy".

By the way, switching to RStudio is probably a good idea:  it's a much better GUI than the one that ships with R.  It has a menu item to open a new copy, you don't need to go looking for the shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, this is the first thing I thought about. Imagined there would be a less "elementary" solution, for lack of better wording.